# Compress over 180k files

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I am not even close to an expert in the infrastructure matter but I am trying to lend a hand to someone who's even worse than I am in this matter.

We need to compress 184k **specific files** into a tar.gz but we don't know how to do it and, through the posts we found, instructs how to compress only through pattern.

The command that we know is the basic one, **tar -czvf filename.tar.gz files**, but I can't imagine it for a list of specific files, I believe that I'll need a script for it or something similar.

We have a file that contains all the file paths that we need already. I thought of compressing the entire folder as well, but there are over 1 million files in there, so, there is no how to use this approach.

Can someone point me the way that I should follow in order to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have a file that contains all the file paths that we need already

Investigate `--files-from` option of `tar`; [`man 1 tar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) says:

> `-T`, `--files-from=FILE`
>   get names to extract or create from `FILE`

Your basic command will become something like

```
tar -czvf filename.tar.gz -T mylist.txt
```

[Similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8033857).

Comment: This was quick! Thank you very much, it is precisely what I needed. I guess I didn't find the answer since I didn't know which terms to use :$

Comment: @Banns general rule of thumb  is to run the command with `--help` or `-h` to see what parameters it supports. Otherwise `man tar` should show you the manual page for the program where there might be more descriptive usage examples.